# Getting text of children tags with CSS selector with Scrapy returns nothing

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

While its a very common question at first, I have tried many different approach to scrap all the text recursively from the following html code, but for some reason none of them worked:

```
<span class="coupon__logo coupon__logo--for-shops">




      <span class="amount"><b>20</b>%</span>

      <span class="type">Cupom</span>



</span>
```

What I tried :

```
p.css('span.coupon__logo coupon__logo--for-shops *::text').get()

p.css('span.amount ::text').get()

p.css('span.amount *::text').get()
```

And even a xpath one:

```
p.xpath('//span[@class="coupon__logo coupon__logo--for-shops"]//text()').get()
p.xpath('//span[@class="amount"]//text()').get()
```

The best thing I got was `p.css('span.amount *::text').getall()`, but it will extract the text from all of the concurrences, what requires me to create a code to organize them individually, while is way better if i could get only the text of the current instance, especially because I'm looping trough many of them, and because it would be vulnerable to any changes from the website .

Comment: Do you want to get all the text inside the `span` tags?

Comment: @SuperUser, Yes, in this case, it would be '20% Cupom'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of getting all the text of all the children of `<span class="coupon__logo coupon__logo--for-shops">` you can get the text of specific children.

CSS:

```py
scrapy shell file:///path/to/file.html

In [1]: ' '.join(response.css('span.coupon__logo.coupon__logo--for-shops span *::text').getall())
Out[1]: '20 % Cupom'
```

xpath:

```py
scrapy shell file:///path/to/file.html

In [1]: ' '.join(response.xpath('//span[@class="coupon__logo coupon__logo--for-shops"]/span//text()').getall())
Out[1]: '20 % Cupom'
```

If you have more `span` tags and you only want `amount` and `type` you can use this:

CSS:

```py
scrapy shell file:///path/to/file.html

In [1]: ' '.join(response.css('span.coupon__logo.coupon__logo--for-shops span.amount *::text, span.type::text').getall())
Out[1]: '20 % Cupom'
```

xpath:

```py
scrapy shell file:///path/to/file.html

In [1]: ' '.join(response.xpath('//span[@class="coupon__logo coupon__logo--for-shops"]/span[@class="amount" or @class="type"]//text()').getall())
Out[1]: '20 % Cupom'
```